# How to return the string after the first space in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to return everything in a string after finding the first space.

for example if my sentence is "This is my life" Then I want to return "is my life"

the function `SUBSTRING_INDEX` will return the first portion of the string so If I did `SUBSTRING_INDEX("This is my life", " ", 1)` I get "this" but I want the exact opposite

How can I manage to return the string?

Thanks

Comment: You can use that in combination with its LENGTH or a REPLACE

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a combination of `SUBSTR()` and `INSTR()`

```
SUBSTR("This is my life" FROM (INSTR("This is my life", " ") + 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Select Right(YourField,CHAR_LENGTH(YourField)-Instr(YourField,' ')) from YourTable